# Spring boot HTTPS-TLS

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

I just want to know while configuring ssl on spring boot services, if i don't mention anything for following two properties, what will be the default value for that?

1. server.ssl.ciphers
2. server.ssl.protocol
3. server.ssl.enabled-protocols

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-server), there are no default values for:

```
server.ssl.ciphers 
server.ssl.enabled-protocols
```

But `server.ssl.protocol defaults` to TLS